# _Viewstart with controller action

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

So my current (and I believe this is the default way) to use _ViewStart.cshtml is to do this:

    `Layout = "~/Views/_SomeSideMenu.cshtml";`

Now my sidemenu is a bit complicated so it requires a controller. But I cannot figure out how to call a controller action for the ViewStart and let it return the PartialPage for it.

My current workaround involves using @Html.Action() in the _SomeSideMenu.cshtml file and fill TempData with the things I need. 
Normally I would want to put that data in the ViewBag or Model, but these are not available since the Html.Action does not return the _SomeSideMenu.cshtml.

How would one go about calling the controller action to return the PartialPage that is found in the _ViewStart page?

Comment: `_SomeSideMenu.cshtml` does not sound like its a `Layout` (which might include a banner, sidebar, footer and the main body of a view). It sound more like a partial view or component that should be included in a Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you cannot do this in the `ViewStart` file. `ViewStart` is a file that can store common functionality related to all the views. These pages can also be nested, so if you have multiple controllers, each controller’s views can have their own `ViewStart` page.

You should add your sidemenu into a Layout page. You could add some conditions to have this output into layout page. For sample, jere, we have an action filter which add a key into `ViewBag` and we use this key to have a state for a sidemenu (state like open or close and position in left or right).

You also could change your default layout page in your view just doing what the ViewStart page does, chaging the Layout property.

```
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/CustomLayoutPage.cshtml";
```